# ASP.NET Core Data Protection cross platform encryption provider

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, encryption, .net-core

I'm trying to use the asp.net core DataProtectionProvider with a single database backing a server farm.  I have a IXmlRepository implemented for the store and I'm successfully supplying the same certificate to 2 machines running my server.  I verified I'm using the same purpose strings in the same order, but when I try to unprotect from machine b a string that machine a encodes, I'm getting a generic CryptographicException.

Would it matter if machine a and machine b are 2 different operating systems? (Linux vs windows server)

The exception I'm getting is:

> {System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Exception of
>   type 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' was thrown.
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.UnsafeNativeMethods.ThrowExceptionForBCryptStatusImpl(Int32
>   ntstatus)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.UnsafeNativeMethods.ThrowExceptionForBCryptStatus(Int32
>   ntstatus)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.GcmAuthenticatedEncryptor.DecryptImpl(Byte*
>   pbCiphertext, UInt32 cbCiphertext, Byte*
>   pbAdditionalAuthenticatedData, UInt32 cbAdditionalAuthenticatedData)
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.Internal.CngAuthenticatedEncryptorBase.Decrypt(ArraySegment`1
>   ciphertext, ArraySegment`1 additionalAuthenticatedData)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[]
>   protectedData, Boolean allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, UnprotectStatus&
>   status)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.DangerousUnprotect(Byte[]
>   protectedData, Boolean ignoreRevocationErrors, Boolean&
>   requiresMigration, Boolean& wasRevoked)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect(Byte[]
>   protectedData)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.DataProtectionCommonExtensions.Unprotect(IDataProtector
>   protector, String protectedData)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that the provider had the folder name for the top level purpose.  I'm assuming this is to isolate the key storage when stored in the registry.  The solution was to add to the configuration setting the ApplicationName so it uses that instead of the folder which was different on the two different machines.

example:

```
services.AddDataProtection()
                .UseCryptographicAlgorithms(new AuthenticatedEncryptorConfiguration()
                {
                    EncryptionAlgorithm = EncryptionAlgorithm.AES_256_GCM,
                    ValidationAlgorithm = ValidationAlgorithm.HMACSHA256
                })
                .SetApplicationName("MyCommonName");
```